# Conditions for a pushforward of a involutive vector bundle to be involutive

Tags: reference-request, vector-bundles, submersions

I know that the following statement is true, but I would like to find a reference for it so I don't have to write the proof. Do you guys have a reference?

> Let $\Omega$ and $\Omega'$ be smooth manifolds and let $\mathcal V \subset \mathbb C T \Omega$ be an involutive fiber bundle. Let $f : \Omega \to \Omega'$ be a submersion and suppose that for all smooth sections $X$ of $\ker f_*$ and all smooth sections $Y$ of $\mathcal V$, it holds that $[X, Y]$ is a smooth section of $\mathcal V$, then $f_*(V)$ is an involutive subbundle of $\mathbb C T\Omega'$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This follows from the fact that $f_*[X,Y] = [f_*X,f_*Y]$, which is stated and proved in many textbooks on manifolds.

Comment: @DeaneYang, I don't see the point of you argument. Given two vector fields $X,Y$ you cannot assure that $f_* X$ and $f_* Y$ are well defined vector fields. I think this has to be proven by means of 1-forms...

Comment: @AntonioJPan, thanks for pointing this out. My comment does appear to be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This is proved in Problem 2.57 of ``Analysis and algebra on differentiable manifolds: a workbook for students and teachers (2012)''.